# Can I save iOS NSString to Rails DateTime like this?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

I make an iOS app with Rails background.

I used to save iOS NSDate to Rails DateTime directly like this.

```
NSdate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDictionary *params = @{@"rails[dateTime]":date,};
```

However, I found out that this code makes bug when users disable 24 hour times in iOS Settings.

(NSDate: Wed Jan  1 00:00:00 2020 will be 2019-12-31T03:00:00.000Z inside Rails datetime.)

So, I decided to insert NSString instead of NSDate like this, and It solved the above 24 hour times issue and seems work fine.

```
NSdate *date = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale           = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSDictionary *params = @{@"rails[dateTime]":dateString,};
```

Is it the correct way to save String to Rails Datetime like this?

Comment: ya you can use option 2

Comment: Have you tried dealing epoch time? Makes saving dates a lot easier. Rails knows to take the seconds and set as datetime

Comment: Do you mean it is easier to save epoch time on Rails side instead of dateTime from the beginning?  Maybe I should have done that before releasing the app...